# Docker Compose Tomcat Can not connect to postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, tomcat

I have 2 containers. One of them postgresql, one of them tomcat.
I tried to start applications but always getting o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. error. Please help me i don't have much time.
Best regards.

I tried different type of docker composes. But i got always same error.

```
16:48:09.557 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

My connection url

```
db.user=admin
db.password=123456
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://moneytransferdb:5410/moneytransfer
```

My docker compose yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  moneytransferdb:
   image: postgres
   restart: always
   ports:
     - "5410:5432"
   volumes:
     - mydatavol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
   environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: admin
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
     POSTGRES_DB: moneytransfer
   container_name: moneytransfer
   networks:
     - main
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
     - ../tcmb/tcmb-service.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/tcmb.war
    container_name: tcmb
    depends_on:
     - moneytransferdb
    links:
     - moneytransferdb
    restart: always
    networks:
     - main
volumes:
  mydatavol: {}
networks:
  main:
```

Comment: For inter-container communications you always need the service-internal port, here 5432.  You don't specifically need a `ports:` declaration unless you want the database to be reachable from outside of Docker space.

Comment: (In the name of simplicity, also consider removing `container_name:`, `links:`, and all of the `networks:` sections; you can delete all of these without interfering with your containers' ordinary operations.)

Comment: Ty David. It worked

Answer (score 1):

Change your connection settings to this:

```
db.user=admin
db.password=123456
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://moneytransferdb:5432/moneytransfer
```

Port mappings make container ports available to the host but are not used by other containers. For them only container ports matter.